# Ajax success: function (data) not premmision 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my simple ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my/dir/",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

When i execute it on my localhost (whit brackets live preview) it generates a html file with data of the directory,  with which i can parse data with some jquery like:

```
$(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function () {
```

It  works flawless! But when I execute the same ajax function on my host provider, it gives a **403 (Forbidden)** error, and it generates an html file with error stuff, like

> You do not have permission, please contact your host provider etc.

They told me it is because there is no index file to execute in this directory.. So they confused me more then they helped me.

Is there a workaround to not to create manually index files in every directory?
Or is it that i'm missing something with *$.ajax*

Here is my full source code, if it matters:

```
$('#accordion2 a').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("added")) {
        $(this).addClass('added');
        var popid = $(this).attr('href');
        var dir = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "../images/com_droppics/" + dir
            , success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function () {
                    var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                    $(popid).append("<img class='zoomable draggable' style='position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;' src='" + filename + "'>");
                    $(".draggable").draggable({
                        revert: "invalid"
                    });
                    $(".draggable").disableSelection();
                })
                $('.zoomable').click(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('zoom');
                    $(".zoomable").not($(this)).removeClass('zoom');
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Again.. it works great on my localhost, when I click on "#accordion2 a", it opens a popup and appends all the images with the provided directory

Comment: look up CORS for what's going on

Comment: @manonthemat for a URL that's local to the current address?

Comment: Saying there's no "index file" in "this directory" meant there wasn't any index.php/index.html file able to be served over the request. Some configs forbid access to directories only so if you don't have the default index.php file to serve the request, it may 403 upon request.

Comment: @Pekka웃, you're right. How stupid of me to think about that, when the issue can't be that.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server probably doesn't have [directory listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) activated (which is probably what is giving you the file list on your local server, which probably is running Apache).

You may be able to activate that on your remote server, depending on what server software it is running and how it is configured.

Try creating (or opening) a `.htaccess` file in your root directory (or, if it's just one directory you want listed, directly in that directory), and have it say

```
Options +Indexes
```

Then, enter the directory you want to get the list from, and see what happens. You may either still get the 403, a 500 error, or a directory listing. In the first two cases, you'd need to talk to your web provider and see whether they can help you.

Comment: @Alfonso, please note that very few admins will allow their public facing directories to be browsed. Big security concern.  However, you can create a server side object that will create the list for you and return that.

Comment: Options +Indexes is giving 404, and it generates some html response with 3 tags in it, title, pre, img and nothing more... UPDATE here is fiddle with the resonse https://jsfiddle.net/804vdmkb/

Comment: @Alfonso that looks like an ok response - a directory listing of an empty directory, no?

Comment: Yeah it looks great, but the directory is not empty :/ here is the same ajax execution on my local host https://jsfiddle.net/vo1zo17o/ UPDATE with the same directory https://jsfiddle.net/804vdmkb/1/

Comment: @Alfonso Then the files in the directory don't have the permissions necessary to be displayed/accessed by the web server.